# How to access the original buffer when running M-x compile and friends?

Tags: elisp, hooks, compilation

For example, take any buffer. Maybe one named `my-file`. I want to run `M-x compile` in it and have access to the `my-file` buffer in `compilation-finish-functions`. You'd think think might work:

```
(setq compilation-finish-functions
      (lambda (buf string)
        (message "Buffer name: %s" (buffer-name (other-buffer buf)))))
```

But it actually echos `my-file`'s `other-buffer`. `current-buffer` just returns the compilation buffer.

How would I reference the `my-file` buffer in a `compilation-finish-functions` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While hardly a clean alternative, a workaround would be to advice `compile` and store the calling buffer in a "global" var. This wouldn't work for concurrent executions of `compile` though. So keep that in mind.

Comment: That works for my needs, I'm not sure why I didn't think of advice before. Instead of using a variable to store it I'm just using a `:before` advice.

Comment: That's even better :)